# VB.NET cross compatibility with C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, interop

I have a C# project with a generic interface

```
public interface IMyFoo<T> { void DoSomething(T instance); }
```

I also have a C# project with an interface that inherits from several IMyFoos

```
public interface IMyBar : IMyFoo<Type1>, IMyFoo<Type2> { ... }
```

Everything works fine in C# land (including the scenario below which doesn't work in VB).

I have a VB .NET project that references this C# library.

I have an instance of IMyBar and try to use as follows:

```
Dim instance as MyType1 = ...
Dim bar as IMyBar = ...
bar.DoSomething(instance) ' This generates a compile error: 
' 'DoSomething' is ambiguous across the inherited interfaces 'IMyFoo(Of MyType1)' and 'IMyFoo(Of MyType2)'.
```

What's up? I can DirectCast like this and it works fine...but I'd REALLY rather not

```
DirectCast(bar, IMyFoo(Of MyType1)).DoSomething(instance)
```

Comment: Relationship between `MyType1` and `Type1` and `Type2` is somewhat unobvious.

Comment: gaearon: MyType1 and MyType2 are simply unrelated concrete classes defined in the C# project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably going to have to [cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa711871):

Unlike other types, which only derive from a single base type, **an interface may derive from multiple base interfaces. Because of this, an interface can inherit an identically named type member from different base interfaces**. In such a case, the multiply-inherited name is not available in the derived interface, and referring to any of those type members through the derived interface causes a compile-time error, regardless of signatures or overloading. Instead, conflicting type members must be referenced through a base interface name.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. It's really a pretty poor excuse on Microsoft's part and I'm hoping this isn't yet another unsolvable relic of a Microsoft half-baked implementation. The article you cited is dated 2003...In 7 years, I'm hoping maybe they fixed this?

Comment: I don't think you'll see this fixed anytime soon. Here's the 2010 version. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1wz55xc.aspx

Comment: Chris is correct, it isn't fixed, I believe it all first came to light with office interop

Comment: @Microsoft: If anyone out there is reading this: Literally, I would be ashamed if I produced these kinds of half baked solutions all day long.

Answer (score 1):

Just to go into further details, the reason VB doesn't directly support what you are doing is because what you showed is just a special case of a class implementing two interfaces with the same method. Whenever VB sees this it forces a cast to make it explicit which one you are intending to use. The VB designers decided that this would make code less error-prone. C# goes further and assumes that you know what you are doing and lets you make that call. You can make C# get the same basic error by using the more generic case of two interfaces with the same method:

```
public interface IMyFoo1 { void DoSomething(string instance); }
public interface IMyFoo2 { void DoSomething(string instance); }
public interface IMyBar : IMyFoo1, IMyFoo2 { }
public class MyTestClass : IMyBar
{
    //Explicit interface declaration required
    void IMyFoo1.DoSomething(string instance) { }
    void IMyFoo2.DoSomething(string instance) { }
}

string s = "";
IMyBar bar = new MyTestClass();
bar.DoSomething(s);//The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties...
```